# How to dynamically log bug into JIRA using script or code

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am using XStudio- a test management application and it currently contains my testcase resulst(pass/fail). I am planning to dynamically log bug into JIRA using XStudio. Kindly let me know if any plugins are available to do the same or should I write script to log defects. If writing script is a good option, please help me to write the script to log bug and invoke the script from XStudio. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Jira JIRA Remote API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference). You should choose between REST, SOAP, XML-RPC of JSON-RPC according to your Jira version and the desired scripting language.

To do something similar, I've used python and XML-RPC, you can find a [very good example here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+an+XML-RPC+Client). If you need any help please supply the Jira's version number, which API, and which language.

Good luck!